# accelerometer data has strange frequency behaviour

Tags: fft, filters, motion

I am trying to process accelerometer data from a device strapped on the side of a coffee machine. In the end, I want to be able to classify the data depending on whether its making a coffee, and what type it is (maybe unsupervised?) First though, is trying to clean and preprocess it. My questions relate to how I can improve the pipeline, and hopefully get cleaner and better data to classify.

My basic pipeline, so far, is:

1. Gather data at 1600Hz - this is the highest the device can work at (might be overkill..) .
2. Calibrate the data (ie. it records x~0.01 even while motionless - so I subtract this from everything)
3. Apply a butterworth high pass filter, trying to clean up the "noise" around 0
4. Slice the data, such that each subset lasts 1 second (so 1600 "events")
5. To each subset, apply a fft, moving into freq. space
6. Pick out the top frequency peak from the subset (this is what I would use as input into a classifier in the future)

Part of my goal is to reduce the size of my set, to help with storage, get it into a more workable form, and also get a set easier to do unsupervised classification on. This seems like standard practice too - to transform this sort of data using a FFT, before analysing it.

My raw acc. data looks like:
[image: coffee machine data]

It looks ok I think, theres 4 clear peaks, each lining up to a coffee I made. Then, I perform steps 2,3,4,5 and get out this:

[image]

So, the FFT has certainly transformed my space. However, you can start to see the beginnings of a problem - a pattern has no emerged through the freq. space, kinda streaking across. Then, when I pick out the top peaks I get this:

[image]

And clearly here something is wrong. The peak frequency somehow is dragging across the space.

I can provide code if people are curious as to exactly what has happened. At the moment, my questions are:

- Conceptually, if I want to unsupervised classify my dataset (while reducing file size of my raw data) is transforming with a FFT and pick the peaks the best course of action? Generally, are my steps 1-6 a good starting point?
- Aside from a coding error, is there a conceptual one why I am seeing the strange behavior in my last 2 plots?
- For picking the point to use an input to a classifier, is the peak of the FFT dist. the best place to start? Intuitively, taking the top 5 or so seems sensible, maybe alongside their amplitude?
- I am rather new to all this, and am trying to follow what I find to be "standard practise" when doing signal processing - am I missing something obvious that I should be doing to this data?

Any advice would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: What makes you think it's strange? You're plotting the peak frequency but we don't have the amplitude of the other frequency components.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  As Ben says, you should also perhaps store the peak value (amplitude), not just the frequency value.  The time vs frequency plot shows that not much happens between the peaks, but you can see the low-amplitude "chirps" in between the main peaks (which is where your linear sweep is coming from).  Whether storing this information is enough will really depend on your application. What are you trying to do with the accelerometer data and the coffee machine? Not quite sure what you mean by `what type it is`?  What type of coffee? Is that detectable? How? :-)

Comment: I would try sampling at a lower rate. One of the easiest litmus tests that you can do is to keep the accelerometer stationary on a flat surface. One of the axis should measure gravity. If that's not happening, then there's something wrong with the commands that you're sending to the accelerometer to sample the data. In addition, the device should come with some calibration procedure that you might need to incorporate.

Comment: I felt it was strange because of low-amplitude linear sweep across the almost the whole time series - it doesnt seem like natural behaviour. However, going forward I will save a (frequency, amplitude) tuple of the top 3 peaks. 

By "what type" I meant is it a latte or americano, etc. I think it might be possible, as when you use the machine the vibrations it makes (at least, by ear) are quite different (i.e. each coffee activates different parts of the machine for different times). By understanding how a segment of the time series has vibrated, maybe you can deduce the coffee type?